# How to access other Store records from Model's convert method in ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am trying to have a calculated field inside a Model that looks something like `value (maxValue)`, where `maxValue` is the maximum value among all other records currently loaded (think current page of a Grid).

Model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'value'},
        {name: 'calculated_value', convert: function(value, record){
            //how to access all the records here, not just the current one?
        }}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A model is not aware of records, it just represents a single record, and the convert method is intended to allow you to convert the value, or combine other fields into a single value (note unless you define "depends" to reference other fields in this instance the convert is only called when the data is loaded and not if the fields it depends on change).

When you create a grid, the grid uses a store, the store contains a collection of records, and this would be the place to do this.

Within the config for your store you could add a listener for 'datachanged' which will fire whenever records are added or removed from the store, from here you could work through all the records in the store, work out a max value, and update records with it.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Example',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'example.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    listeners:{
        datachanged:function(store){
            var maxValue=store.max('value');
            store.beginUpdate();
            store.each(function(record){
                record.set('calculated_value',maxValue);
            });
            store.endUpdate();
        }
    }
});
```

If you are loading the store from a server, then you will be implementing a reader, this would possibly be an even better place to do this.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Example',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'example.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            transform: {
                fn: function(data) {
                    var maxValue=0;
                    Ext.each(data.items,function(item){
                        if(item.value>maxValue) maxValue=item.value;
                    });
                    Ext.each(data.items,function(item){
                        item.calculated_value=maxValue;
                    });
                    return data;
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Its also worth clarifying if you really need to duplicate this value, I presume you then want to reference somehow within the grid, perhaps in a renderer, instead you could just set the value once on the store:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Example',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'example.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    listeners:{
        datachanged:function(store){
            store.maxValue=store.max('value');
        }
    }
});
```

Then within your grid column config, add/update a renderer (in this example I display value as a percentage of maxValue):

```
{
    dataIndex:'value',
    renderer:function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view){
        return Math.round((100/store.maxValue)*value)+'%';
    }
}
```